# Comparing arrays and objects for a filter system

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects/arrays that I need to compare for a filter system, and here's a crude set of data:

```
var books = [{
        'title': 'book a',
        'relatedIds': [1, 2],
        'authorId': 1,
    },{
        'title': 'book b',
        'relatedIds': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'authorId': 2,
    },{
        'title': 'book a',
        'relatedIds': [1],
        'authorId': 3,
    }];

var filters = {
    'relatedIds' : [1, 2, 3],
    'author': [1, 2]
};
```

What I expect to see for the above filters that `book a` (has related ids 1 and 2 and author id 1 from filter) and `book b` (has related ids 1, 2 and 3 and author id 2 from filter).

I would not expect to see `book c` as even though it has the correct related id, its author is 3 which is not in the filter.

I've tried using Lodash's filter method:

```
_.filter(books, (book) => {
    ....
```

But I'm failing to see how I can do comparisons based on arrays from the filter to either an array or int/string on the books.

Comment: You didn't actually show what you tried when using the lodash filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

- `filter` is used to get only the desired output from the original data
- `some` is used check any `relatedId` of element is available in `filters` 's `relativeId` or not
- `includes` is used to check whether a given value is available or not in the array.

```js
var books = [{'title': 'book a','relatedIds': [1, 2],'authorId': 1,},{'title': 'book b','relatedIds': [1, 2, 3, 4],'authorId': 2,},{'title': 'book a','relatedIds': [1],'authorId': 3,}];

var filters = {
    'relatedIds' : [1, 2, 3],
    'author': [1, 2]
};

let op = books.filter(({relatedIds,authorId})=>(
   relatedIds.some(id=> filters.relatedIds.includes(id))
   && filters.author.includes(authorId)
))
console.log(op)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, do you mind explaining this line `relatedIds.some(id=> filters.relatedIds.includes(id))` and what is happening?

Comment: @panthro add explanation, you can check

Comment: Thanks, I'm still unsure as to why you use `some` and then `includes`? Surely `some` would be enough to check if any `relatedId` of element is available in filters 's `relativeId` or not?

Comment: @panthro since `relatedId` is array in your `data` and `filter` as well, so you need to compare each value of `data's relatedId` with `filters relatedId` unless you find a match

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now,`some` element in the `relatedIds` needs to `includes` in the `filterIds` and only at least one of the items needs to pass this test - correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.intesection()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersection) to find similar items in `relatedIds` by checking the length of the result (0 if no similar items). Use [`_.includes()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes) to check if the `authorId` is in the filters' `author` array:

```js
const books = [{"title":"book a","relatedIds":[1,2],"authorId":1},{"title":"book b","relatedIds":[1,2,3,4],"authorId":2},{"title":"book a","relatedIds":[1],"authorId":3}];

const filters = {"relatedIds":[1,2,3],"author":[1,2]};

const result = _.filter(books, o =>
  _.intersection(o.relatedIds, filters.relatedIds).length &&
  _.includes(filters.author, o.authorId)
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```